# Rewrite spaces in url query on nginx (with express)

Tags: regex, node.js, nginx, express

I have an nginx server load-balancing several express (node.js) servers. Every time I get a request with unencoded white spaces on the query express closes the connection and nginx thinks it is down. Then it makes the same request to the next express upstream, gets the same result, and consequently sets the whole cluster down, when nothing is really down.

Looking at the logs, those requests are coming from old browsers like Mozilla 4. I can also emulate the behaviour with curl:

```
curl "http://mysite.com/path/?q=foo bar"
```

I've tried adding a rewrite rule with all sorts of regular expressions to encode that white-space with %20:

```
rewrite     "^(.*)\ (.*)$"  "$1%20$2"    last;
rewrite     "^(.*)\s(.*)$"  "$1 $2"    last;
rewrite     "\s"  "%20"    last;
...
```

But nothing seems to work. Is it a problem on my regular expression or is just that nginx does not allow to just switch a character?
Do you know any other way to solve the problem? Maybe on the express/node level, to avoid it to just close the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a good look at this, I don't think that nginx is the best tool for this task. You cannot replace all occurrences without using a perl module (correct me if I'm wrong).

These requests are not HTTP compliant, so you are correct to reject them.

If you **absolutely** wanted to accept them, you could still do it with just node.js:

The HTTP parser is exposed through `http._connectionListener`. This function takes a TCP socket, parses the verb, query and headers and emits a `request` event (the function passed to `createServer` automatically listens).

In your case, the function never triggers the event, but closes the connection before you get the change to do anything else.

You could hijack it to rewrite the request before the HTTP parser sees it:

```
var util = require('util'),
    http = require('http');

var oldConnectionListener = http._connectionListener;

http._connectionListener = function (connection) {
  var cleaner = new QueryCleaner(connection);

  oldConnectionListener(cleaner);
};
```

`QueryCleaner` would be a stream that rewrites the query if incorrect and then passes the rest of the stream through.

Comment: Yes, I did. It doesn't work either. The problem seems to be just replacing characters on the query part of the url. If I try to replace, for example, the character 'a', it replaces the a's in the path, but not in the query. Does it give any clue?

Comment: It just doesn't work replacing with %20 because it encodes the result afterwards. I mean, after applying the regex, it will change the % with %25, resulting in %2520.

Comment: OK, I get it. You can use the $args variable to do that.

Comment: Still does not work. Could you provide an example of how i can rewrite the $args itself?

Comment: I am returning a 409 error code. If you know how to replace the white-spaces with the %20 that would be perfect, otherwise I can put an answer with my workaround. At least it does not break the whole cluster...